# Is there any formal explanation for the sensitivity of AdaBoost to outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

AdaBoost is known to be sensitive to outliers & noise. However, the explanation seems to be hard to found or nontrivial.

Comment: This paper may be of interest: [Long and Servedio (2010). Random Classification Noise Defeats All Convex Potential Boosters.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-009-5165-z)

Comment: have you looked at Elements of statistical learning section 10.4-10.6.  basically the exponential loss makes it sensitive to outliers vs eg logloss (binomial deviance in fig 10.4)